# Logical to Physical Address

Tags: operating-systems

I have an exam coming up and my teacher posted a practice exam for it.  Problem is that I solved the question but I am not sure if I am doing it right or getting the right answer as he refuses to give us an answer key to confirm if we got it right or not.  The question goes

Given a simple page table as the figure below.  For each of the following logical address, determine the physical address.  Assume that page size is 1024 bytes.

a) x1E53

b) x3746

Table below

[image]

Can someone explain the steps on how to get the answers?  I believe I got something but I am not sure if its right or not.  I got for a 1x8000253 and for b 0xF800346 but once again I am not sure if I did this right.  Sorry and thank you.

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: Peculiar. A practice test without answers barely qualifies as practice in my book.

Comment: Yeah, I went to him for help before I posted this question and he said he can't give me the answer and I just do not understand why as its not even homework.

Comment: My results have the same LSBs, compared to yours, but the MSBs differ. How did you get 0x8000253 for a, for instance?

Comment: So I did this based on what I saw somewhere else.  I get the binary of 1E53 which is 0001 1110 0101 0011.  Then 1024 is 2^10.  So I split the binary based on that.  000111 and 1001010011.   Then there I looked at 00 0111 and got 7 and looked at the 7th entry and got 60000.  Then I got the binary for that which is 0110 0000 0000 0000 0000.  Combined 0110 0000 0000 0000 0000 and the other half of the other binary plus the 00 ignored for the 7 so I get. 0001 1000 0000 0000 0000 0010 0101 0011.  Which gives me 1 80000253.  Like I said, I do not know how to do this and yeah...